# Errors in my dart code and other errors with android studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

Note: I am a beginner in flutter and dart so please make the answers understandable

1. When I opened the avd manager and ran the phone, it showed "unable to locate adb" and then opened the phone.
2. (It's takes a long time to load)
3. When I ran the program in android studio, I got these errors: (also got the same errors in flutter console)

```
C:\Flutter SDK\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\dart.exe" --enable-asserts --enable-vm-service:58163 C:\Users\user\my_app\lib\main.dart
lib/main.dart: Warning: Interpreting this as package URI, 'package:my_app/main.dart'.
Observatory listening on http://127.0.0.1:58163/ozLrsFGRARk=/

/C:/Flutter%20SDK/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons.dart:9:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' as ui show Paint, Path, Canvas;
       ^
/C:/Flutter%20SDK/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons.dart:10:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^
/C:/Flutter%20SDK/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/app.dart:5:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
       ^
/C:/Flutter%20SDK/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/app_bar_theme.dart:5:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^
/C:/Flutter%20SDK/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/arc.dart:6:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^
/C:/Flutter%20SDK/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/bottom_app_bar_theme.dart:5:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^
/C:/Flutter%20SDK/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/bottom_sheet.dart:6:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^
/C:/Flutter%20SDK/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/bottom_sheet_theme.dart:5:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^
/C:/Flutter%20SDK/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/button_bar_theme.dart:5:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^
/C:/Flutter%20SDK/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/card_theme.dart:5:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^

Process finished with exit code 254
```

4. "system UI is not responding" when the phone loads

Flutter doctor gave me no errors

Nothing appears in the phone

It seems it can't find "dart:ui"?

I don't even know what that is, im following the steps in this book:

[https://www.amazon.com/Beginning-App-Development-Flutter-Cross-Platform/dp/1484251806/ref=sr_1_3?dchild=1&keywords=flutter&qid=1593032118&sr=8-3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1484251806)

Also note: I'm new to stackoverflow, this is my first question

Im using the flutter create sample

One more thing, how can I connect my iphone and run the sample on it?

Thank you.

Comment: Don't need to worry, everything is feasible to fix :)   First, run *flutter doctor" to see if you have everything nicely setup. Make sure you followed all steps for proper setup according to official [flutter documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install) 

Let us know your findings

Comment: [√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.900], locale en-US)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.0)
[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[√] VS Code (version 1.46.1)
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 1 category. Everything is fine, the emulator wasn't opened, that's why no devices available and I checked the documentation and did everything @vinipx

Comment: Yeap, don't forget to:  **sudo apt install android-tools-adb**
and then **adb devices**

Comment: @vinipx ? the flutter console doesn't know what it is 'sudo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: just asking, do you know what unable to locate adb is? I tryed a lot of things already but adb is in my platform-tools so it should locate it @vinipx

Comment: Follow these instructions here to [Install Flutter in Windows](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows)

Comment: @vinipx I got a error, it's below under the answer

Comment: @vinipx He is running Windows 10. `sudo apt` won't work. @user13806962 adb is used to communicate with your Android device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow! These are quite a lot of questions. I hope that I can help you with your problems.

2. I personally recommend that you test your app on a physical device whenever possible. Virtual devices are also running pretty slow on my system.
3. `dart:ui` is a dart library that contains lots of important stuff.
   If you opened a flutter project, you need to run `flutter pub get` in your console to load all the used libraries into your project.
4. "System UI is not responding" is occasionally displayed in Android when the device is running slowly and therefore hangs here and there. I suspect that this is due to the poor performance of the virtual Android device on your PC.

---

> Nothing appears in the phone

Your project could not be compiled and downloaded to the mobile phone due to the errors. Therefore nothing appeared on the display.

> im following the steps in this book

You can also have a look at the online examples on the flutter website. I find them very well described and interesting even for beginners. Have a look at: [Write your first Flutter app](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/codelab)

> One more thing, how can I connect my iphone and run the sample on it?

To run your project on your iPhone, you need a Macbook or iMac. I recommend you to work along this article of the flutter online documentation: [macOS install](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos) (further in this article: [Deploy to iOS devices](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#deploy-to-ios-devices)).

Good luck!

Comment: got this error: "Error: No pubspec.yaml file found.
This command should be run from the root of your Flutter project.
Do not run this command from the root of your git clone of Flutter." @josxha

Comment: so what physical devices can I use to run my flutter app? sorry for using your time

Comment: The `pubspec.yaml` includes a list of all packages that are not embedded into flutter, used assets and more. The error you mentioned can show up, when you are not inside of your project. Navigate with `cd C:\path\to\your\project\` inside your project and try again.

Comment: You can deploy your project basicly on Android, iOS, Linux, Windows, MacOS and the Chrome Web Browser. However, only Android and iOS are fully supported so far (web support is currently in the beta stage). If you use MacOS, you can use an Android device or iPhone/iPad. With a Windows PC, unfortunately only Android devices are possible, because iOS development requires Apple's development environment xCode, which is only available for MacOS.

Comment: im still getting the same errors, not sure why @josxha

Comment: and i used flutter pub get for the project folder, it cant find dart ui

Comment: This seems really weird to me.Did you install the Flutter plugin in Android Studio? (File > Settings > Plugins) If so, you can try to let Android Studio create a new project for you. This should make it clear if there is just a problem with your test project. Go to "File > New > New Flutter Project" and select a "Flutter Application". Follow the dialog until you have created your project and try to run it.

Comment: Yes, "Flutter Application".

Comment: When the project is set up and Android Studio detects a suitable device it shows up inside of the dropdown menu on the top of the window. You can run your app with the green play button right hand.

Comment: android studio crashed when i ran it, but im gonna try again...

Comment: it just wont display on the phone, it was working with no error and then the console stopped putting anything but the screen on the phone went black and restarted the whole thing so im just not gonna do this

Answer (score 0):

Create a new virtual device with a different screensize.