# Flutter/Dart on a IOS device?

Tags: ios, android-studio, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

How can I run my flutter program on a IOS device?

I'm gonna use a iphone6s.

I'm using a windows 10.

I'm either using visual studio code or android studio.

Last thing, how can I use visual studio code to run my flutter program on any device?

Android-studio you just press run but visual studio code confuses me.

Comment: You will have issues to run the app in a Apple device as far I know.... you can do it but it could be time very consuming as you need some remote service to run the app for you and send you the app back for you to deploy it... your productivity will not be the same.

Comment: @ClaudioRedi thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Errors in my dart code and other errors with android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62564029/errors-in-my-dart-code-and-other-errors-with-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run on IOS from a Windows machine. Apple doesn't allow building to IOS from anything but MacOS. You can run in Visual Studio Code by opening a terminal and typing `flutter run`.

Comment: Thank you! I know someone who has a macbook air, do I have to do the whole setup again to run it there? @Benedikt J Schlegel

Comment: @user13806962 I am not sure if there is a way to run "through" a Mac from your PC. I don't know of any. But you would only need Flutter itself on their Mac, and then you could run it from the Terminal.

Answer (score 0):

While you can develop an application for IOS using Windows, you can't test or deploy  it unless you're using a MacOS, which I personally think is a dirty way to force any developer to buy an overpriced hardware just for this sake. But anyway there seems to be some ways around it, i'll give you some articles that are probably worth reading.

1. [Developing and debugging Flutter apps for iOS without a Mac](https://medium.com/flutter-community/developing-and-debugging-flutter-apps-for-ios-without-a-mac-8d362a8ec667)
2. [How to sign Flutter apps for iOS automatically without a Mac](https://medium.com/flutter-community/how-to-sign-flutter-apps-for-ios-automatically-without-a-mac-a2dc9cfa5a6c)